# Magento 2 grunt watch is not pre-processing LESS for main locale

Tags: magento2, less-css, grunt

My `core_config_data` table has `general/locale/code` set to `en_IE`. When I run `grunt exec:<theme-name>` and then `grunt less:<theme-name>`, CSS is generated in two separate locale folders, en_GB and en_IE. Both have the correct output CSS.

However, when I run `grunt watch` and then change a LESS file, the change is registered and the page refreshes, but the change doesn't take effect in the browser. I can see that this is because the CSS is only updated in one locale (en_GB) and not the other (primary, en_IE).

Is there a way to tell `grunt watch` to refresh CSS for all locales at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I had added my theme to the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` file, but had specified `en_GB` instead of `en_IE`.

To put it another way, the locale inside `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` didn't match that set in the `core_config_data` table.

Answer (score -3):

ow to Installing and configuring Grunt

1. Install node.js to any location on your machine.
2. Install Grunt CLI tool globally. To do this, run the following
   command in a command prompt:

   ```
   npm install -g grunt-cli
   ```
3. Rename *'Gruntfile.js.sample'* to *'Gruntfile.js'*   And
   *'package.json.sample'* to *'package.json'*
4. Install (or refresh) the node.js project dependency, including
       Grunt, for your Magento instance. To do this, run the following
       commands in a command prompt:
        cd your_Magento_directory_name

   ```
   npm install
   npm update
   ```
5. Then use Grunt commands

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This might be useful but it does not answer the question at all. Answers on StackExchange should provide a solution for the question. This one answers a different question: "How to install and configure Grunt"